# Perl - LWP::UserAgent; slow response - more then 4096 characters

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I'm trying to retrieve interface statistics data via HTTPS GET from a remote network device. The script is working, however when a response is larger than 4098 characters the connection hangs for 60 seconds. Please help ! I'm slowly going crazy.

```
my $interface_getAll = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $URL );
$interface_getAll->content( 'session_id=' . $sessionID . '&format=json&method=network.interface.fetchAllStatistics' );

my $res = $ua->request($interface_getAll);
$interface_getAll_rData = $res->content;

my $InterfaceValues = decode_json($interface_getAll_rData);
print Dumper($InterfaceValues);
```

I can't replicate this issue when using curl or wget, I get a response instantly. The API on the remote device responds to GET requests only. If you think that my code is invalid I'm open to any suggestions.

request URL example/format:

```
https://192.168.99.51:443/services/rest/V2.1/session_id=b121c16aa0c0361e9bebe5bd67e60a&format=json&method=network.interface.fetchStatistics
```

Comment: Did you test again another remote instance, to make sure the problem is on the client side? Or did you try to fetch the data for example with curl or wget?

Comment: A GET with content is not only odd but plain invalid. You probably need to have a POST or PUT request.

Comment: @ikegami: the newer RFC 7231 is more clear in this regard: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1 -  "A payload within a GET request message has **no defined semantics**; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing  implementations to **reject the request.**"

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, "No defined semantics" just means the server gets to define its own semantics.  The part about some devices rejecting the request is problematic, though, because the device could be a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

> The API on the remote device responds to GET requests only.

Using a message body with a GET request has no defined behavior. In fact [RFC 7231 clearly says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1)

> A payload within a GET request message **has no defined semantics**; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to **reject the request**.

Thus if your API really requires a GET with a message body you should consider the API broken.

But given the URL you show I would rather suggest that the API does not require a message body but that you simply use LWP in the wrong way.
According to your example URL the `session_id=...` is not inside the message body but actually part of the URL and should be added to this, i.e.

```
 $URL = "https://192.168.99.51:443/services/rest/V2.1/session_id=...."
```

And while you could just append it directly to the URL a more clean and readable way would be to construct your URL with [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) as suggested by ikegami@:

```
 use URI;

 my $url = URI->new("https://192.168.99.51:443/services/rest/V2.1/");
 $url->query_form(
    session_id => $sessionID,
    format     => 'json',
    method     => 'network.interface.fetchAllStatistics',
 );
 my $interface_getAll = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $url );
 # no setting content() here
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you need to fetch url

> h﻿ttps://192.168.99.51:443/services/rest/V2.1/session_id=b121c16aa0c0361e9bebe5bd67e60a&format=json&method=network.interface.fetchStatistics

but your code is fetching url

> h﻿ttps://192.168.99.51:443/services/rest/V2.1/

The following is how you fetch the correct url:

```
use URI;

my $url = URI->new("https://192.168.99.51:443/services/rest/V2.1/");
$url->query_form(
   session_id => $sessionID,
   format     => 'json',
   method     => 'network.interface.fetchAllStatistics',
);

my $response = $ua->get($url);
```

Using `$url->query_form` ensures your values are properly encoded.